# Printing a different number of pages per sheet

Tags: pdf, printing

I'm trying to print a PDF document printing four pages per sheet, but I need each section starting on a new sheet and each section has seven pages; due to this, I need to print 4 pages on the first sheet, then 3 on the second, then 4 on a new sheet, and so on.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What are your PDF software, printer model and printer software?

Comment: Usually I use Foxit and a Canon LBP2900 with its drivers, but if possible I was looking for something general, so it wouldn't be tied to the printer, and I could install new software.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to do this on a regular basis, these three solutions might be faster than a programming approach:

1. Get some free / freemium pdf editor (a google search should easily yield a few), and insert a blank page after every section. Then print the whole pdf.
2. Print pages 1 - 7. Then print pages 8 - 14 and so on.
3. if there is one completely blank page in the pdf, let's say page 100, you can also insert the following in the print dialogue: `1-7;100;8-14;100;15-21;100` and so on. This will print the pages exactly in the order you insert them

Comment: Do you know a sotware that lets inserting those blank pages in bulk? If the document has many sections, inserting the blank pages one by one would be time consuming.

Comment: @Mauro. Acrobat DC: see this article - https://answers.acrobatusers.com/I-2100-page-PDF-I-add-blank-page-3rd-page-What-efficient-way-q251027.aspx

Comment: @Mauro here's a free / cheap solution: http://www.a-pdf.com/faq/how-to-insert-new-pages-to-every-two-pages-of-existing-pdf.htm  Haven't tested.